# Spring MVC: Saving values added into a form to load later

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have a ParticipantsController.java which can add/delete/edit participant names.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import questForTheBest.domain.Participants;

@Controller
public class ParticipantsController {

@InitBinder("participant") // Validator for participant model
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(new ParticipantsValidator());
}

List<Participants> participantList = new ArrayList<>(); // create a list of participants

@RequestMapping("/participants") // Participants page
public String testing(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("participantList", participantList);
    return "forms/ParticipantMaster";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/participantDetail", method = RequestMethod.GET) // Shows participants
public String participantDetail(@ModelAttribute("participant") Participants participant, @RequestParam(value="participantId", required=false, defaultValue="-1") int participantId) {

    if (participantId >= 1) { // Shows participants with an id greater than or equal to 1

        Participants p2 = participantList.stream().filter(p -> (p.getId() == participantId)).findAny().get(); // gets participants
        participant.setId(p2.getId()); // sets participants id
        participant.setName(p2.getName()); // sets participants name
    } else {

        participant.setId(Participants.lastId); // otherwise create a new participant id
        Participants.lastId++; // increment last id
    }
    return "forms/ParticipantDetail";
}   

@RequestMapping(value = "/addParticipant", method = RequestMethod.POST) // Adding participants page
public String addParticipant(@Valid @ModelAttribute("participant") Participants participant,BindingResult result, Model model) {


    if (result.hasErrors()) { // validation
        return "forms/ParticipantDetail";
    }
    else {


    participantList.removeIf(p -> (p.getId() == participant.getId()));
    participantList.add(participant); // add participants


    model.addAttribute("participantList", participantList);
    return "forms/ParticipantMaster";
    }
}   

@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteParticipant", method = RequestMethod.GET) // Deleting participants
public String deleteParticipant(@RequestParam(value="participantId", required=false, defaultValue="-1") int participantId, Model model) {

    participantList.removeIf(p -> (p.getId() == participantId)); // removes the participant with id
    model.addAttribute("participantList", participantList);
    return "forms/ParticipantMaster";
}



}
```

I wish to be able to:  everytime a list of names are entered into the form I would like them to be saved when a button "Save current names" is pressed so that they can be later loaded again on another page by being able to be selected from a drop down box and then a "load" button is clicked.

The overall application is a leaderboard so I would like the same participants to be able to be saved for example so it can be loaded when a certain class in school will need to use the leaderboard.

Does this require the use of a database or is it possible without.

Thank you.

Comment: Currently my participants are displayed on a table and no persisitent data is kept everytime the app is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you will need the database for permanent storage of the leaderboard data on the solid state device (SSD storage) given your use case as memory(RAM) gets flushed/reset on machine reboot or crashes. You can have a layer of in-memory or a distributed cache as a layer above the database layer using an in-memory data structure like you have used a list in your implementation or redis respectively to make your application efficient for serving reads.

You got to have a Database Access Object (DAO) layer in your application for performing database related operations.

Please refer to this link to understand how DAO layer is implemented in spring boot

https://www.baeldung.com/jsf-spring-boot-controller-service-dao

Hope this helps!